# Unpacking / Packing AOSP recovery image using abootimg fails to boot

Tags: android, android-source, recovery, initrd

I built a recovery.img (using flo lunch setup) for my Nexus 7 device using AOSP source code.  I can use it like:

```
$ adb reboot bootloader
$ fastboot boot recovery.img
```

However, when I unpack and re-pack the recovery.img file using abootimg utility (without making any modifications to ramdisk) and retry to boot using recovery.img, my Nexus 7 simply goes into Google splash screen loop.  Device keeps rebooting after coming to splash screen.

For details, here are my steps:

```
$ ls
recovery.img
$ abootimg -x recovery.img
$ abootimg-unpack-initrd initrd.img
$ abootimg-pack-initrd myinitrd.img ./ramdisk
$ abootimg -u recovery.img -r myinitrd.img
```

Resulting updated recovery.img doesn't work as intended, even though its simply an unmodified copy of original recovery.img file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some weeks ago, but with the boot image, not the recovery... The only solution I found to be working is to extract the initfs from the img file extracted from the device after being installed by using `dd` command:

```
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0pX of=/sdcard/recovery.img
(Where X is the number of your recovery partition)
```

You can find the number of your recovery partition by using:

```
ls -l /dev/block/platform/soc.0/7824900.sdhci/by-name
(Please, note this path may be device specific, but should be similar for all. This one worked for Sony Xperia X Compact device)
```

Then, the recovery.img file being extracted, you can now extract the initfs and repack again